# How to send an action from a controller to a component?

Tags: ember.js

I have a controller with multiple instances of a component.

```
// Template.
{{#each foo in foos}}
  {{my-component foo=foo}}
{{/each}}
```

In my controller, I would like to validate `foo` for each component.

```
// Controller.
actions: {
  validate: function () {
    // for each component, call the "validate" action/function/whatever
    // and deal with the result.
  }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: And what is the effect cause by an invalid item? It merely removes it?

Comment: @givanse For now, just a `console.log` in my controller with each result. It's just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. I use the Ember two-ways binding feature. As you can see below, my `foo` data is now something like:

`{ item: <my_data>, isValid: <boolean> }`

So, my template becomes:

```
// Template.
{{#each foo in foos}}
  {{my-component foo=foo.item foo=foo.isValid}}
{{/each}}
```

And in my controller, I return a promise that resolves if all components `isValid` properties is true.

```
// Controller.
validate: function () {
  var that = this;

  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var isValid = that.get('foos').isEvery('isValid', true);
    return isValid ? resolve() : reject();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
foos: null,// populated using set() somewhere 

validate: function() {
  var foos = this.get('foos');
  foos.forEach(function(item) {
    // process
  });
}.property('foos')
```

Nothing more needs to be done in your template, the {{each}} is bound to foos.

For a more elaborated example where the template changes on item (foo item) changes, you can use an `Ember.ArrayProxy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a property called `validate` in your controller and pass that property into the component. That property is bound between controller and component and you can then watch (observe) it inside your component and perform validation when it gets set to true (in the controller).

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  validate: false,
  actions: {
    validate: function(){
      this.set('validate', true);
    }
  }
});

App.MyComponentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  foo: null, 
  validate: false,

  needsValidation: function(){
    alert("Validated!");
  }.observes('validate')
});
```

Then, in your template you pass the `validate` property in like so:

```
{{ my-component foo=item validate=validate}}
```

See the working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/famehi/1/edit?html,js,output)